# Why redeclaration of a static member is denied

Tags: c++, declaration, static-members

I thought that we can redeclare a name any times in any context. But

```
class A 
{
    static int a;
    static int a;
};
```

returns a compile-time error:

```
test.cpp:4:13: error: redeclaration of ‘int A::a’
test.cpp:3:13: note: previous declaration ‘int A::a’
```

What names can be redeclare actually?

Comment: Wasn´t this answered some minutes ago in you previous question?

Comment: how do you make the difference between the first and the second `a` ?

Comment: @Raxvan I'm interested in where this redeclaration denied in the standard. Can you answer me?

Comment: @deviantfan It is two defferents questions.

Comment: @St.Antario: Not really, the are only the other way around and should get the same answer. See Mike Seymours comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624844/one-definition-rule-in-c#comment36274096_23624863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 9.2/1 [class.mem]

> A member shall not be declared twice in the *member-specification*, except that a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined, and except that an enumeration can be introduced with an *opaque-enum-declaration* and later redeclared with an *enum-specifier*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard (9.2 Class members, paragraph #1)

> A member shall not be declared twice in the member-specification,
>   except that a nested class or member class template can be declared
>   and then later defined, and except that an enumeration can be
>   introduced with an opaque-enum-declaration and later redeclared with
>   an enum-specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the other answers, your code is not only a redeclaration but also a redefinition, which clearly violates the one-definition-rule.

Comment: There is no any redefinition. Actually,  `declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification 25 (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a function-body, it declares a static data member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4)`

Comment: For more details please see 3.1.2 section

Comment: You're right. I've read too quickly and missed that you define a class not a function.